# using Activity in Android Widget

Tags: java, android, android-widget

i need an Activity in my Widget Provider. Is there any way to realize that?
The problem is: I want to write a little Facebook Widget but: The Facebook API needs an Activity in the Authorize Function... without this function i get an Facebook Error. Xan i call a Object in my Activity from this Widget ? Or, can i "share" this Object global?

```
Facebook facebook = new Facebook("X X X");
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() { });
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

Facebook api requires an activity to display a dialog with authentication, you should create an Activity in your app and start it to display auth dialog.

Comment: Yes. Thats working. But how can i send data from my activity to the Widget? :-/

Comment: You should implement DialogListener which is passed as the third parameter.